# Hibernate throws StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization, deserialization

I have a class like this,

```
class SampleClass implements Serializable {
    String name;
    Serializable fieldName;
}
```

And another class like,

```
class AnotherClass implements Serializable {
    SampleClass sampleClass;
}
```

where both class has their getter and setter methods.

In the main class, I'm getting the `sampleClass` variable from getter function, and trying to use the `sampleClass` objects. But when I'm using that, I encounter the error like, `could not deserialize`.

How to access the members of `SampleClass`, or shall we have field members of type `Serializable` ?

Thanks.

---

Edited:
I am using hibernate, which uses many to one relation between aemploye and aaddress tables.

I created the Hibernate configuration file, and Reverse engineering file in net beans, for the above two tables.

Then I generated the POJO class.

The class and xml are:

`Aaddress.hbm.xml`

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="hibernatetutor.tablebeans.Aaddress" table="aaddress" schema="public">
    <id name="sno" type="int">
        <column name="sno" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="street" type="serializable">
        <column name="street" />
    </property>
    <set name="aemployes" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="address" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="hibernatetutor.tablebeans.Aemploye" />
    </set>
</class>
```

`Aemploye.hbm.xml`

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="hibernatetutor.tablebeans.Aemploye" table="aemploye" schema="public">
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="aaddress" class="hibernatetutor.tablebeans.Aaddress" fetch="select">
        <column name="address" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="name" type="string">
        <column name="name" />
    </property>
</class>
```

`Aaddress.java`

```
public class Aaddress implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int sno;
    private Serializable street;
    private Set aemployes = new HashSet(0);

    public int getSno() {
        return this.sno;
    }

    public void setSno(int sno) {
        this.sno = sno;
    }

    public Serializable getStreet() {
        return this.street;
    }

    public void setStreet(Serializable street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public Set getAemployes() {
        return this.aemployes;
    }

    public void setAemployes(Set aemployes) {
        this.aemployes = aemployes;
    }
}
```

`Aemploye.java`

```
public class Aemploye implements java.io.Serializable {

    private int id;
    private Aaddress aaddress;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Aaddress getAaddress() {
        return this.aaddress;
    }

    public void setAaddress(Aaddress aaddress) {
        this.aaddress = aaddress;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

`Main.java`

```
private void getData() {
    Session session = HibernateUtils.getInstance().openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Aemploye where id=:id");
    query.setParameter("id", 1);
    Aemploye a = (Aemploye) query.uniqueResult();
    Aaddress a1 = a.getAaddress();
    System.out.println(a1.getStreet());
}
```

The error is:

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.fromBytes(SerializableType.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.type.SerializableType.get(SerializableType.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2096)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1380)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1308)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3044)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:836)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.invoke(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:150)
    at hibernatetutor.tablebeans.Aaddress$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$44bec229.getStreet(<generated>)
    at hibernatetutor.Main.getData(Main.java:33)
    at hibernatetutor.Main.main(Main.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:753)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:209)
    ... 29 more
```

Comment: add proper getters and setters to it

Comment: Can you post some code? It is hard to help otherwise.

Comment: This is not a serialization issue per se, more to do with the Hibernate framework. You should consider retagging and reformulate the question.

Comment: Why would you want to set the type of the street field to Serializable?

Comment: The column of the street in the table aaddress is text[]. Im using postgreSQL. So to match with the column, im using type=serializable, in mapping xml

Comment: @Boopathy Why don't you use a `String` attribute for `street` instead of `Serializable`? Also, the problem is most likely caused by the database column having type `TEXT`, which is not appropriate for binary data. If you want to store binary (such as a serialized object), I'd suggest to change its type to `BYTEA`.

Comment: +1 because of the Serializable! It was killing me, scenario, Oracle 11g Database, TIMESTAMP(6) columns were being mapped as Serializable by Hibernate Tools (Jboss) => java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue. Upgrading to latest hibernate **5.0.2.Final** solved **java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header** issue in my case

Answer (score 1):

On the basis of both the question, and some of the info from the comment section, I believe your troubles are caused by the following:

You have for some reason chosen the street attribute to be of type serializable. In your table this column has been defined as of type `TEXT`. Hibernate probably manages to save the serialized data to the column, but the database probably does not manage to keep them unaltered. Therefore, on retrieval, the now garbled serialized fail to deserialize.

The solution is, *as Petr Pudlák noted*, to get your mapping to be correct. If you choose a suitable binary type, such as `BYTEA`, then you will be able to store the binary data unaltered. The retrieval should then work.

This is not the right solution IMHO, which would be to choose a suitable data type in your java code in the first place. Having the type of street to be Serializable is confusing to anyone viewing your code. `String` would probably make more sense, and would also be a good fit for the column type `TEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a getter doesn't involve serialization unless you have some very unusual framework to do this.

I suggest you look at the exact stack trace (and post it in the question) and see where the exception is actually occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your classes, and it works for me:

```java
import java.io.*;

class SampleClass implements Serializable {
      String name;
      Serializable fieldName;
}

class AnotherClass implements Serializable {
      SampleClass sampleClass;
}

public class Ser {
    public static void main(String argv[])
        throws Exception
    {
        SampleClass s = new SampleClass();
        s.name = "name";
        s.fieldName = "fieldName";

        AnotherClass a = new AnotherClass();
        a.sampleClass = s;

        // serialize the classes to a byte array
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        oos.writeObject(a);
        oos.close();

        // deserialize the classes from the byte array
        ObjectInputStream is
            = new ObjectInputStream(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream( os.toByteArray() ));
        a = (AnotherClass)is.readObject();
        is.close();

        // print something
        System.out.println(a.sampleClass.name);
    }
}
```

Can you post the exact code that causes the problem?

Comment: Please look at the edited area.. I'm using Hibernate SQL to get the value from the tables. session.createQuery("from Aemploye"). This will populate Aemploye and Aadress beans with the values from tables. Now i can access the values in Aemploye bean but, when i try to access Aadress, it is showing the above error...